# Why is my file seemingly being read incorrectly?

Tags: python, file, io, file-read

In Python I want to read from a large file:

```
def aggregate(file_input):
    import fileinput
    reviews = []

    with open(file_input.replace(".txt", "_aggregated.txt"), "w") as outp:
        currComp = ""
        outp.write("Business;Stars_In_Sequence")
        for line in fileinput.input(file_input):
            reviews.append(MyReview(line))
            if(currComp != reviews[-1].getCompany()):
                currComp = reviews[-1].getCompany()
                outp.write("\n" + currComp + ";" + reviews[-1].getStars())
                outp.flush()
            else:
                outp.write(reviews[-1].getStars())
                outp.flush()
```

The file looks like this:

```
Business;User;Review_Stars;Date;Length;Votes_Cool;Votes_Funny;Votes_Useful;
0DI8Dt2PJp07XkVvIElIcQ;jkrzTC5P5QGJRoKECzcleQ;5;2014-03-11;421;0;1;0
0DI8Dt2PJp07XkVvIElIcQ;cK78PTjb65kdmRL9BnEdoQ;5;2014-03-29;190;0;1;0
```

and works fine if I use only a small part of the file, returning the right output:

```
Business;Stars_In_Sequence
Business;R
0DI8Dt2PJp07XkVvIElIcQ;55555455555555515
LTlCaCGZE14GuaUXUGbamg;555555555
EDqCEAGXVGCH4FJXgqtjqg;3324133
```

However, if I use the original file it returns this, and I cant figure out why

```
Business;Stars_In_Sequence
ÿþB u s i n e s s ; 
0 D I 8 D t 2 P J p 0 7 X k V v I E l I c Q ;                 
L T l C a C G Z E 1 4 G u a U X U G b a m g ;         
E D q C E A G X V G C H 4 F J X g q t j q g ;
```

Comment: What version of python? And have you looked at what's actually in your input file at the point where the output appears 'wrong'?

Comment: your file seems to be some kind of unicode/16-bit format with a BOM header.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.13. I have looked at the file and it seems to be wrong from the second line onwards. But what I dont understand is why it works correctly if I just copy the first ~200 lines of the file and try it with them

Comment: If it works on one line, it should work on all others if they have the same format.  Can you put any error checking into `MyReview` to notify you when it sees an ill-formed line?